# HTML content doc file with 1 page size showing 1 page in Libre but 2 pages in MS Word

Tags: html, css, ms-word, libreoffice, doc

I'm creating a HTML content file with .doc extension through python. That html table with 1 page size showing exactly 1 page in Libre, but when I open it in in MS Word it shows 2 pages of content.

I think MS word not accepting page size or styles given inside style tag I guess. Like this I given:

```
  <style type="text/css">   
            @page { size: 8.27in 11.69in; margin: 0.4in }  
            tr{page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto; border: 1px solid #2b628d;   }
            table{ font-family: Calibri !important; font-size: 8pt !important;    width:100%;    page-break-inside: auto;}  
            p { font-size:8pt !important; font-family: Calibri !important; }
            font{ font-size:8pt !important;  font-family: Calibri !important;color:#336699 !important; }     
    </style>
```

How to bring the same way as it shows in libre writer?

Comment: i think msword prefers .docx ext

Comment: it supports .doc extension. When I checked with .docx format, MS Word shows corrupted file. But the problem is even though if we create in .docx format, how to apply style in that?.

Comment: HTML is not Word's "native" format, nor is the conversion (what works or doesn't work) documented anywhere. Word does have its own "round-trip" HTML, but that isn't documented, either. You can see it, however, by saving a Word document as a web page then inspecting the HTML. But chances are you won't get the same result in two different applications - they are *different applications* and each will follow it's own rules for conversions and laying out pages for *printing*.